# Static hint in variable length arrays

Tags: c, arrays, c99

I'm a bit confused at the difference here, in C99:

```
int myfunc (int array[n], int n) { ... }
```

will not compile. As far as I know you must always put the reference to the array size first, so it has to be written:

```
int myfunc (int n, int array[n]) { ... }
```

But if you supply the static keyword, this works absolutely fine:

```
int myfunc (int array[static 1], int n) { ... }
```

This order if far preferable to me, as I'm used to having arrays come first in a function call, but why is this possible?

Edit: Realising that the third example isn't actually a VLA helps...

For reference, this was the piece of code I was looking at that led to the question:

```
int sum_array(int n, int m, int a[n][m])
{
  int i, j, sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
      sum += a[i][j];
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this works absolutely fine"? In order to create a comparable example with `static`, you have to write it like this `int myfunc (int array[static n], int n)`. And it won't "work fine" for the very same reasons. You last example "works fine" because you replaced `n` with `1`. `static` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It works exactly as the previous definition (so long as you switch the function arguments around, obviously) -- both will take an array of any length and return the same result.

Comment: `int myfunc (int array[], int n)` will work the same way as `int myfunc (int array[static 1], int n)` except that in the first prototype the `array` argument cannot be `NULL`.

Comment: @teppic: All of your declarations will take array of any length (with "no less then 1" restriction for the last one). But again, you ask why the third declaration is possible. I don't understand what triggered this question. Why wouldn't it be? What exactly do you find surprising in the third declaration?

Comment: @AndreyT: as the third form is only used with VLAs, it didn't seem to make sense in line with the other two possible ways of declaring them, but the explanation about the identifier being defined first does make sense.

Comment: @teppic the last form has nothing to do  with VLA, it has been introduced as an optimization hint for the implementation and you can use it with non-variable length arrays.

Comment: @ouah: That might explain my confusion even more. I thought they were the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why

```
int myfunc (int n, int array[n]) { ... }
```

is valid and

```
int myfunc (int array[n], int n) { ... }
```

is not is due to the lexical scoping rules of C. An identifier cannot be used before it has been introduced in the scope. There are a few exceptions to this rule but this one is not one of them.

**EDIT**: here is the relevant paragraph of the C Standard:

> (C99, 6.2.1p7) "Any other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator."

This rule also applies to parameters declaration at function prototype scope.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for error has already been explained to you: you have to declare `n` *before* you can use it in other declarations.

However, it is worth noting that none of these declarations actually declare variable length arrays, as you seem to believe.

It is true that syntax with `[n]` was first allowed in C99 and that it is formally a VLA declaration, but nevertheless in the given context all of these declarations declare `array` as a parameter of `int *` type, just like it has always been in C89/90. The `[n]` part is not a hint of any kind. The fact that you can use `[n]` in this declaration is indeed a side-effect of VLA support, but this is where any relationship with VLA ends. That `[n]` is simply ignored.

A "hint" declaration requires keyword `static` inside the `[]`. So, your declaration with `[static 1]` is equivalent to classic `int array[1]` declaration (meaning that `1` is ignored and the parameter has type `int *`) except that it gives the compiler a hint that at least `1` element must exist at the memory location pointed by `array`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because arrays must be declared with a constant value so you cannot create an array using a variable size and therefore cannot pass an array with a variable size. Also if it is just a single-dimension array you don't need to pass a value in at all, that is the point of passing in the second parameter to tell you the length of your array.

To get this to work properly just write the function header like this:

```
int myfunc (int myArray[], int n) {...}
```

The order shouldn't matter, but you cannot have the size of an array you are passing be variable it must be a constant value.

Comment: Your suggestion is a simple way to get the program to compile, but C99 **does** introduce something called “Variable Length Array”, often shortened to VLA when the context is clear, as you can see in the discussions around this question. (I didn't downvote you but whoever did may have been annoyed by this technicality in your answer)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GCC and are willing to use some of their extensions, you can accomplish what you wish right here:

```
int myFunc (int len; /* notice the semicolon!! */ int data[len], int len)
{

}
```

The documentation for this extension (Variable Length Arrays) is [here](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/ada/gnat/html/gcc_5.html#SEC87).

Please note that this extension is NOT available in [clang](http://clang.llvm.org) for some reason, I'm not quite sure why, though.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Derp, scope, of course.

My question is; why do you need to do it at all?  You're really getting a pointer anyway (you can't pass arrays to a function in C, they degrade to a pointer, regardless of the function's signature).  It helps to let the caller know the expected size of the input, but beyond that it is useless.  Since they are already passing the size, just use...

```
int myfunc(int arr[], size_t size) {
    // ...
}
```

Or

```
int myfunc(int *arr, size_t size) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In this instance the order of the parameters is important - the second form will always compile, the first one will never. The actual function I've written here is just for demonstrating my question.

Comment: @teppic: Yeah, that's true.  It doesn't change the fact that this is useless and a waste of time. You still get a pointer to the first element in the function.

Comment: Yeah, here the function wasn't really important itself, just the syntax was confusing me. I suppose the main advantage of the form here over the traditional arr[] is that the array created is definitely of size n.

Comment: @teppic: There is no array being "created"; you simply receive a pointer to the first element, regardless of the size.  You cannot pass arrays to functions; they degrade to pointers.

Comment: @teppic: Try this in your function; `size_t s = sizeof(arr)`.  `s` will always equal `sizeof(int*)`

Comment: I meant in the array passed - it's an explicit reference to the size of the array. It's more useful in a two dimensional verison of this as you can say func(int a, int b, int arr[a][b]); without knowing the size of either.

Comment: @teppic: It's not though because in reality you can pass in an array of any size.

Comment: I know you can pass an array of any size by passing it as a pointer, but in the style above you can act on the array just as you would a standard array (e.g. arr[1][2]) inside the function, without declaring or assigning anything else, and without knowing a constant in any of the dimensions.